# Divide a integer value in for method and show the start and end limit

Tags: php

I need to  divide the integer value and show the start and end limit 
example:

consider a integer value 666 and i  need to divide it by 60 and show output like this in an array

output `[0,60][60,120][120,180]`....

note : this code have some mistakes forgive me

```
$num=666;
$initialRows=60;
$iterationCount = round((count($num) / 60));;
for ($i = 0; $i < $iterationCount; $i++) {
    $rows = $initialRows * $i;
    $startLimit = $rows;
    $index = $initialRows + $startLimit;
    #if last Iteration
    if ($i == $iterationCount && $i!=1) {
        $rows += $initialRows;                            
        $index = count($num);
        $startLimit = $rows - $initialRows;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

division is also summing;) so take a look at this trick:

```
<?php

$n = 666;
$d = 60;

$x = 0;
$res = [];
while ($x < $n) {
    $res[] = [
        $x,
        $x = $x+60
    ];
}

var_dump($res);
```